# ActionBar object is returned as null

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I get actionBar object below as null, and hence a `NullPointerException` when executing `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`. Following is my code which is called from onResume of the Fragment.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Followwing is the theme I apply to the activity in the onCreate:

```
 <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/green</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/greenD</item>

    </style>
```

My application has minimum api level set to 14.
Please help me, explain why is the `ActionBar` object returned as null.

**EDIT:**
    `getActivity().getActionBar();` returns null in `Fragment`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getActionBar() returns Null (AppCompat-v7 21)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435231/getactionbar-returns-null-appcompat-v7-21)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getActionBar() returns null after SDK update to 5.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526564/getactionbar-returns-null-after-sdk-update-to-5-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `getSupportActionBar()` when you use `AppCompatActivity` instead of `getActionBar()`.

**EDIT**

When you use `AppCompat` theme you have to use `AppCompatActivity`.

Example code how to get `ActionBar`:

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
if(activity != null && activity instanceof AppCompatActivity) {
   AppCompatAcitivyt appCompatActivity = (AppCompatActivity) activity;
   ActionBar actionBar = appCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar();
   //your code
}
```

Comment: I am using it in a Fragment, not AppCompatActivity, and since my minimum version is 14, do I still need to use the support library?

Comment: it depends on your Activity that you use. But in any way, you use Theme.AppCompat.Light... so you have to use AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **appCompat** you need to use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`